# Unable to instantiate an obj into a file and use it in another

Tags: javascript, singleton, quill

I'm trying to implement the singleton pattern in order to instantiate an object in a file and reuse the same instance in another file. It's obvious that I'm not understanding something elementary. Any directions for a better understanding?

```js
let editorDiv = document.createElement('div');
editorDiv.setAttribute('id','editor');
document.body.appendChild(editorDiv);

//a.js
function singleton(){
  let _singleton;
  let quillOptions = { modules: { toolbar: true },
                  placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
                  theme: 'snow'
                }  
  if (!_singleton) {
    _singleton = new Quill('#editor', quillOptions) 
  }
  
  return _singleton;
}

//b.js
//instantiate
let quill = singleton();

//c.js
//get instance in order to use api
let quillInstace = singleton(); 
//Ex: quillInstance.getText();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your `_singleton` cache variable is scoped inside your `singleton()` method, meaning that each time you call it, it would be empty.

You should store it differently:

```
//a.js
//this is now a global var for this file
let _singleton;

function singleton(){
  let quillOptions = { modules: { toolbar: true },
                  placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
                  theme: 'snow'
                }  
  if (!_singleton) {
    _singleton = new Quill('#editor', quillOptions) 
  }

  return _singleton;
}
```

or use the handful [lodash memoize method](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#memoize) that does the job for you =)

Comment: Thank you! I wrote the code wrong, but you sent me on the right path. I'm skipping lodash for now. I want to first figure out vanilla before jumping to shortcuts.